# Right Shift Operator With Brackets

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I don't understand why there's a difference between this code:

`byte b = (byte) (0xff >> 1);`

(so now b = 01111111),

and this code:

`byte b = (byte) 0xff;`

`b >>= 1;`

(but now b = 11111111).

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

In the first code, `(0xff >> 1)` is 255 >> 1, which is 127. That is calculated with ints and then you cast it to a byte. 127 as a byte is `01111111` bin.

---

In the second code, you start with `(byte) 0xff`, which is `11111111` bin, which is the two's complement representation of -1 in 8 bits. So `(byte) 0xff` is -1.

When you perform shifting, the byte value `-1` is promoted to the int value `-1`. That's `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` bin.

Shifting it right one place with the *arithmetic right shift operator*, `(-1) >> 1` gives you `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` again, because the `>>` operator on a negative number moves the bits to the right and fills in the left with ones instead of zeroes.

Then, since you're using `>>=`, the result is cast back to a byte to be stored in `b`. That only retains the last 8 bits, which are `11111111`.

Alternatively, if you used the *logical right shift operator*, `(-1) >>> 1` would give you `01111111 11111111 11111111 11111111` in binary (a zero followed by 31 ones). Since the last 8 bits are the same, this would still give you `11111111` when it is cast back to a byte.